# Extract strings from a file offset

Tags: linux, string, bash, command-line

Is there a way to use the "strings" command on a file, so that it will extract strings from a specific offset?

I tried to use dd and then strings but it appears to be slower than expected -

```
dd if=/tmp/bin of=/tmp/out skip=13000 count=140000 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

Is there any optimized way of extracting strings from a specific offset in the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "appears to be slower than expected"?  You can use strings as a filter and just do `dd ... | strings`.  Other than the annoying banner dd prints to stderr, that should work just fine.  Or use `perl` or any other tool to get the data you want, and pipe that to `strings`

Comment: @WilliamPursell It appears slower than using python to open the file, going to the offset and copying the data to another file

Comment: A Python script that does all the work you code in it will almost always be faster than a series of piped bash commands.